# Verificar campo de formulario antes de enviar petición - Django

Tags: django

Soy nuevo en Django, y estaba realizando una app para control de stock y ventas. El problema que tengo, es que al crear una venta, necesita verificar que haya stock disponible, y en caso de que no haya, enviar un mensaje de error o similar, pero no consigo hacerlo.

**models.py**

```py
class Producto(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    stock = models.IntegerField()
    precio_venta = models.FloatField()
    precio_stock = models.FloatField()

class Venta(models.Model):
    producto = models.ForeignKey(Producto, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cantidad = models.FloatField()
    fecha = models.DateTimeField('dia vendido',auto_now=True)
```

**views.py**

```py
def new_venta(request):
    form = NewVentaForm()
    return render(request,'ventas/form_venta.html', {'form':form})
```

**forms.py**

```py
class NewVentaForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Venta
        fields = ['producto','cantidad']
```

Tambien quisiera saber si es posible hacerlo con clases genéricas, gracias.

Comment: La venta en cuestión es sobre una serie de productos? o de sólo un producto en particular?

Comment: La venta es sobre un producto que se vende por kilo

Comment: Cual es problema con el producto exactamente? plantea bien tu problema en cuanto al producto para asi facilitar la ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Una opción podría ser que dentro de la función `new_venta()`, se verifique el stock del producto que se quiera, para ello yo crearía una función adicional que se encargue de ver el stock de un producto en particular

```py
def ver_stock(nombre_producto): #recibe el nombre del producto
    producto = Producto.objects.get(nombre = nombre_producto) #recoge el producto encontrado
    if producto.stock > 0: #comprueba que el stock sea mayor que 0
        return True # si es así retorna True
    else:
        return False #de no cumplir retorna False
```

Esta función podría recibir el id, también que sería lo más apropiado, en lugar de recibir como parámetro el nombre.

---

La función anterior se podría usar a la hora de llamar a la función `new_venta()`, pero esta vista además de recibir el `request` debe de recibir el atributo en cuestión, es decir, en este caso el nombre del producto:

```py
 def new_venta(request, nombre_producto): #recibe la request y el nombre del producto
    if ver_stock(nombre_producto) == True:
        form = NewVentaForm()
        return render(request,'ventas/form_venta.html', {'form':form})
    else:
        return HttpResponseNotFound('<h1>Lo sentimos no hay stock de este producto:(</h1>')
```

---

Recuerda que para mandar algún campo adicional a tu vista dentro de las url debe de ir:

```py
url(r'^venta/(?P<nombre_producto>\d+)/$',new_venta, name='ventas'),
```

Dentro de la template cuando llamas a la url, debes de indicarle el atributo que recibe:

```
<a class="btn" href="{% url 'ventas' producto.nombre %}">Venta</a>
```

Comment: El problema es que no se que producto se va a vender, lo que tengo es un formulario con un dropdown con todos los productos

Comment: Puedes ver lo que se ha puesto en el formulario dentro de la view de new_venta nombre_producto= request.POST['nombre_atributo']